# How do i tell my TYPO3 which setup.txt to use?

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typo3-8.x

Having installed the introduction_package and with it the bootrstrap_package, I need to work in a different directory then the bootstrap_package which setup.txt is being used.

What ways are there, so my setup knows which one to use.

I hope this make sense...

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to include typoscript.

1. aside from any extension typoscript ('static templates') you need a template in your root page. Here you can include static templates from extensions and also define your individual part of typoscript.
   Be aware: some extensions include their static templates uncondinioally global (you might remove their typoscript).
2. if you use a [site-package](https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/) you will provide your own typoscript templates (maybe your own `setup.txt`)